# Do I need Passenger Locator Form for Krakow - Prague trip on bus?

Tags: covid-19, poland, czech-republic, prague, krakow

I plan to go from Krakow to Prague on Flixbus. Do I need Passenger Locator Form? Or only EU Covid Certificate is enough?

Comment: @LeosLiterak yep, contact tracing has been a complete failure in Czech Republic, its super annoying that they still demand this form.

Comment: We do have lots of laws and requirements people do not obey and nobody cares. Bohemia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, travelers entering the Czech republic by bus must complete and submit the Passenger Locator Form. [This Czech government webpage](https://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/file/public-health-passenger-locator-form.aspx) shows the form, which says:

> PUBLIC HEALTH PASSENGER LOCATOR FORM
> RULES FOR ENTERING THE CZECH REPUBLIC
>
> All passengers travelling to the Czech Republic have to fill the Public Health Passenger Locator Form before entering the country.
>
> 1 Online form is available on the website
> http://www.prijezdovyformular.cz
>
> 2 After a completed form is sent, you will receive a confirmation email.
>
> 3 You have to submit the comfirmation email before bo[a]rding a plane or a bus and during the border and residence control.

Comment: Why the '[sic]' after "travelling" ?

Comment: @Doc Left over from my law days. "sic" is short for the Latin _sic erat scriptum_, indicating that the quote shows the original text exactly. It's used to indicate that misspellings or other strangeness was in the original, and not a product of the writer's transcription error; here in the US, the word "traveling" is usually spelled with only one letter "l". I did correct the other misspelling (originally it was "bording"), as indicated by the brackets in item #3.

Comment: Except the Czech Republic is not in the USA!  The correct spelling in most of the world is exactly as stated on the document.  There is no "misspellings or other strangeness" in that sentence, only in the way that Americans spell Traveller.

Comment: @Doc True enough. I'll delete it. Thanks.